# Charts.js sets canvas width/height to 0 and displays nothing

Tags: javascript, charts

I am trying to use Charts.js to make the default line plot that they show in their example dynamically and put it in a div that I pop up on a user click.  My code is like this:

```
this.chartCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
this.div.appendChild(this.chartCanvas);
this.chartCanvas.style.height = '480px';
this.chartCanvas.style.width = '900px';
this.chartCanvas.width = 900;
this.chartCanvas.height = 480;
this.ctx = this.chartCanvas.getContext('2d');

this.chart = new Chart(this.ctx).Line(data);
```

When I make the call to "new Chart" my canvas height and width are set to 0 as I can see in the inspector.  When I comment out this call my canvas has the proper width/height and displays as one would expect.  If I manually change the canvas height/width in the inspector my chart still doesn't display.

My "data" object is just what I cut and paste directly from their line chart example here: http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#line-chart-example-usage

Can anyone provide some insight on where I might be going wrong, I am completely new to the library.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It appears that the issue is that the canvas and all its parent nodes cannot have display none at the time the chart call is made so if you are using a chart in a popup you need to show the popup, construct the chart and then hide the popup.

As this Fiddle shows, if you try and construct a chart in a hidden div and then show it on a timeout it does not work.

If you instead show the div, make the chart and then hide the div, it does work.

http://jsfiddle.net/bjudheoq/4/

```
//This will break it
//this.div.style.display = 'none';
this.chart = new Chart(this.ctx).Line(data);
this.div.style.display = 'none';
```

The above fiddle works, but if you uncomment line 40 it does not.

Answer (score 19):

In my case the canvas needed to be wrapped inside an element with the CSS `display: block;`

Comment: This worked for me in my angular5 app. Just put a <div> around the canvas.

Comment: Worked for me inside a hidden tab in a vue app

Comment: Any explanation for why this is the case?

Comment: @krummens because otherwise the code which checks the parent element for the width and height calculation will get a 0 value. Just set on some element: `display: unset` and console log out the elements height with JS: `$0.clientHeight` ($0 is the element) and you will see: 0. (I tried it right now just with your comment) => For elements the display value is initially set (div => block, span => inline-block), for others like Angular new / custom ones not.

Comment: Thanks @SteveHanov It worked for me after adding div around the canvas in ionic angular.

Answer (score 2):

I found an option:

```
options: {
    responsive: false,
    ...
```

This makes conflict with default `true`. I don't know it works properly at the moment.
Ofcourse set the width and height to the canvas and its parent.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works, with the exception of a typo. This line...

```
this.chartCanvs.style.width = '900px';
```

...should be this:

```
this.chartCanvas.style.width = '900px';
//            ^ your code is missing this 'a'
```

And here's a JS Fiddle with that typo fixed: http://jsfiddle.net/dun5dhne/

Also, I strongly recommend opening your browser's developer console when you run into problems. This kind of thing is easy to catch in the console.

Comment: my code actually doesn't have the typo, I put that into stack overflow, but given that your fiddle works I ought to be able to figure it ought from that, ty.  There are no console errors, I always keep it open.

Comment: I wonder if it's a problem with your `this.div.appendChild(this.chartCanvas)` call. In your code, are you sure `this.div` is a reference to a valid `<div>` that exists in the DOM?

Comment: Yes, it is.  I believe I figured out the issue.  If you look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bjudheoq/2/ you can see that if you set the divs display to  'none' and then reveal it on a 1 second timeout, the div displays (a bit red rectangle) but the chart is blank.  If you comment out the this.div.style.display = 'none'; on line 27 then everything works.  Since I am trying to show the chart in a popup that is initially hidden this may be my issue.

Comment: I confirmed this is the issue in my code as well.  If I don't create the chart until after the popup div that holds it is visible then everything works.  ChartJS must use the innerHeight or innerWidth of the container div or something of that nature.