# chart.js Failed to create chart: can't acquire context from the given item

Tags: javascript, node.js, chart.js

I never got into node so I am pretty sure I am doing something massively wrong here since I cannot find any info at all by googling.

I have a django site and I wanted a JS charting library, I chose chart.js.

I installed and like the docs, but after that I am unsure of what to do so I tried to fill in the blanks and follow their guide as much as possible. Here is what my html looks like....

```
<script src="/public/node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.js"></script>

<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>

<script>    
    var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
    console.log(ctx);

    var options = {}

    var data = {
        labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
        datasets: [
            {
                label: "My First dataset",
                fill: false,
                lineTension: 0.1,
                backgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,0.4)",
                borderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
                borderCapStyle: 'butt',
                borderDash: [],
                borderDashOffset: 0.0,
                borderJoinStyle: 'miter',
                pointBorderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
                pointBackgroundColor: "#fff",
                pointBorderWidth: 1,
                pointHoverRadius: 5,
                pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
                pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
                pointRadius: 1,
                pointHitRadius: 10,
                data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40],
                spanGaps: false,
            }
        ]
    };

    var myChart = new Chart({
        type: 'line',
        data: data,
        options: options
    })
</script>
```

I am just trying to get an example working. I put the node_modules directory that was downloaded via npm somewhere where my server would serve them up....and verified they are being served, but then I get this error when I try to build a chart. I took all the chart codes from their docs so I am pretty sure that part is right, but I can't see why I am getting this error.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

You are not passing the 2d context of the canvas (`ctx`) when calling the constructor. From the [documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/usage.html#creating-a-chart):

> To create a chart, we need to instantiate the Chart class. To do this,
> we need to pass in the node, jQuery instance, or 2d context of the
> canvas of where we want to draw the chart.

```
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

Make sure to declare the canvas tag in html ***before*** the script that creates the Chart.js object. Otherwise, the script executes and tries to find a reference to a canvas that doesn't exist. In the script, any of the following formats may be used to get a reference to the canvas, which is then passed to the Chart.js constructor.

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart'); // node
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d'); // 2d context
var ctx = $('#myChart'); // jQuery instance
var ctx = 'myChart'; // element id

var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {/* Data here */},
  options: {/* Options here */}
});
```

Comment: Another reason for this could be that you included Script before your canvas tag, add scripts after you have added the canvas html tag.

Answer (score 152):

Another reason to get the same error, is if the element referred by the id is not a `<canvas>`. I had a `<div>` element in my HTML source, and of course it did not work.

Comment: I had this exact typo!

Comment: Wow, thanks, man. I was really confused why it didn't work, until I removed the div and put the id in the canvas tag.

Comment: Likewise if you've simply omitted the canvas element from your page!! Oh dea.

Answer (score 23):

I am a bit late to the party but if other developers reach this post, make sure you don't reference document or window.
The angular team doesn't encourage accessing the dom variable directly.
Use **ElementRef**  instead

```
import { Component, OnInit, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-compo',
  templateUrl: 'mycompo.html',
})
export class MyCompo implements OnInit {
   myChart:any;
   constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {
   }

  ngOnInit(){
   this.chartit();
  }

  chartit(){
     let htmlRef = this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector(`#yourCavasId`);
     this.myChart = new Chart(htmlRef, {
        //your data here
     });
  }

}
```

HTML as suggested by @mavroprovato

```
<canvas id="yourCavasId" ></canvas>
```

Comment: Looks like querySelector is selecting the *parent* element of the chart. ie: 

`<div #myCanvas>
  <canvas id="canvas">{{ chart }}</canvas>
</div>`

Answer (score 10):

Also, the java script must be after the declaration of the canvas.

Answer (score 6):

Had this error cause I was trying to set the chart on **constructor** instead of **ngAfterContentInit**

I personally have no problem with giving the **canvas id** as string for context

```
this.chart = new Chart('myChartId', {...})
```

Comment: This worked for me but I used ngAfterViewInit

Answer (score 4):

you can use

add this in your template
`<canvas #myCanvas width="500" height="300"></canvas>`

add this to your component

```
@ViewChild('myCanvas') canvasRef: ElementRef;
  constructor()
```

when ready to draw call this

```
 this.ctx = this.canvasRef.nativeElement.getContext('2d');
         this.chart = new Chart(this.ctx, {....})
```

Comment: This implementation worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

I'm using Chart.JS with Angular 9.

This usually happens if there is an ID mismatch with the instantiation of the chart.
Make sure you have an ID attribute in `canvas` element like this -

`<canvas id="myCanvasId">{{ myChart }}</canvas>`

and you have this correctly while instantiating the chart -

```
this.myChart = new Chart('myCanvasId', {
....
}
```

On another screen, I faced the same issue due to the presence of `*ngIf` on the parent element of `<canvas>`.

To overcome this, you can either remove the `*ngIf` from the parent or initialize the chart variable at the beginning with an empty array - `myChart: []`.

Answer (score 2):

Also faced this issue, mine was solved by putting the chart creation in a DOMContentLoaded addEventListener. Of course the CDN and canvas prerequisites have to be met before doing this

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {

    const ctx = document.getElementById("myChart")

    const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: "bar",
        data: {
            labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
            datasets: [
                {
                    label: "# of Votes",
                    data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
                    backgroundColor: [
                        "rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)",
                        "rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)",
                        "rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)",
                        "rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)",
                        "rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)",
                        "rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)",
                    ],
                    borderColor: [
                        "rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)",
                        "rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)",
                        "rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)",
                        "rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)",
                        "rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)",
                        "rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)",
                    ],
                    borderWidth: 1,
                },
            ],
        },
        options: {
            scales: {
                y: {
                    beginAtZero: true,
                },
            },
        },
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is the only solution that worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was using ngIf on canvas and then I moved it to its parent div. In both cases I was getting this error: chart.js Failed to create chart: can't acquire context from the given item.

Even after applying all the above methods, I wasn't able to solve it. So I changed ngIf to ngStyle with display: (condition)? none: block. And it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was using `ngIf` on canvas and then I moved it to its parent div. In both cases I was getting this error: `chart.js Failed to create chart: can't acquire context from the given item.`

Even after applying all the above methods, I wasn't able to solve it. So I changed `ngIf` to `ngStyle` with display: `(condition)? none: block`. And it worked for me.

Comment: I had the same situation with ngIf.  Using ngClass worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Just a little tip. If you fixed the issue by adding a context, but the chart still doesn't show up, then place the `<canvas>` element in a `<div>` element, otherwise it won't display.

Reference: [Charts.js sets canvas width/height to 0 and displays nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32661385/charts-js-sets-canvas-width-height-to-0-and-displays-nothing)

Comment: Please use comments section

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. The solution for me was that I had to write my code after DOMLoadedEvent like this :

`document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() { MY CODE HERE..... });`