# tables in html not displaying in model

Tags: php, html

I have a popup box which needs listing of some data in table. outside there is another table. This popup do not display table . popup do not work if table is there.

```
`<form method="post" action="">
                  <?php echo $message; ?>
                  <table>
                  <tr>
</tr>``
```

View standard Packages

```
    <!-- The Modal -->
    <div id="myModal" class="modal">
        <!-- Modal content -->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <table>
                    <thead></thead>
                    <tbody class="table">
                        <tr>
                            <td>1</td>
                            <td>2</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>3</td>
                            <td>4</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--Model ends--> 
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: This your code is not complete. I've just tested it including the missing part and it works fine. See https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_modal.asp  for the missing part.

Comment: examples are good if we give table in that it is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working perfectly for me please check with this code.
Otherwise, you have a javascript error please check-in console first.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
<div class="modal" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">

        <!-- Modal Header -->
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Heading</h4>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        </div>

        <!-- Modal body -->
        <div class="modal-body">
          <table>
                      <thead>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody class="table">
                          <tr>
                              <td>1</td>
                              <td>2</td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                              <td>3</td>
                              <td>4</td>
                          </tr>
                      </tbody>
                  </table>
        </div>

        <!-- Modal footer -->
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: outer of this i have a form and table this is inside the form wait let me edit the whole code

Comment: It's not an issue you can put form and table inside form it's working please check console first you have a javascript error or not.

Comment: I tried with   <form method="post" action=""><table>...</table></form> this code and it's working perfect for me

Comment: yes i have 1 error in console Chart.min.js:10 Failed to create chart: can't acquire context from the given item

Comment: Yes, that's why your modal popup not working please solve that error first.

Comment: i dont know how to solve that problem . can we display db data without tables

Comment: Please remove  Chart.min.js code. if it's not usable in your code otherwise short it out first.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41280857/chart-js-failed-to-create-chart-cant-acquire-context-from-the-given-item

Comment: can we remove it it is inbuilt from bootstrap i am using its theme won't it affect on others

Comment: yes, you can remove if it's not used in your other pages.

Answer (score 0):

Add th tags in your  thead tag.
Use the following

```
<thead>
   <tr>
     <th></th>
     <th></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

And then in your tbody add tr tags like here

```
<tr>
   Your td should be here
</tr>
```

Comment: Not quite, missing the `<tr>`