# ChartJS implementation in ngFor after data is subscribed from an API call

Tags: angular, data-binding, chart.js, ngfor, subscribe

I was trying to implement doughnut charts individually for all the datasets that I am receiving from an API call in angular with the following code :

demo.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Chart, ChartData } from 'chart.js';
import { MockdataService } from 'src/app/services/mockdata.service';

export class MockDataModel {
    'id': number;
    'running': number;
    "ordered": number;
    "cancelled": number;
    "request_sent": number;
    "declined": number;
    "chart": Chart;
}

@Component({
    selector: 'app-chart-demo',
    templateUrl: './chart-demo.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./chart-demo.component.css']
})
export class ChartDemoComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(public mockService: MockdataService) { }

    data: MockDataModel[] = [];
    ngOnInit(): void {
        var ctx: any = [];
        this.mockService.GetMockData().subscribe(data => {
            this.data = data;
            for (let i = 0; i < this.data.length; i++) {
                ctx.push(document.getElementById(String(data[i].id)));
                let toShow: number[] = [data[i].running, data[i].declined, data[i].cancelled, data[i].ordered, data[i].request_sent];
                let chartData: ChartData<'doughnut'> = {'datasets': [{'data': toShow}]}

                // commenting this and uncommenting the next also not working and giving the same issue
                this.data[i].chart = new Chart(ctx[i], {'data': chartData, 'type': 'doughnut' });

                // uncommenting this and commenting the previous also not working and giving the same issue
                //new Chart(ctx[i], {'data': chartData, 'type': 'doughnut' });        
            }
        });
    }

}
```

demo.component.html

```
<div *ngFor="let d of data">
<h1>{{d.id}}</h1>
<canvas [id]="d.id" width="400px" height="400px"></canvas>
</div>
```

The value of ('data') received from subscription is like the following:

```
[ 
    { "id": 1, "running": 5, "ordered": 3, "cancelled": 2, "request_sent": 4, "declined": 3 }, 
    { "id": 2, "running": 2, "ordered": 3, "cancelled": 2, "request_sent": 4, "declined": 4 }
]
```

but the following messages are shown in the console and the canvases are appearing blank:

> Failed to create chart: can't acquire context from the given item

> ERROR Error: Canvas is already in use. Chart with ID '0' must be destroyed before the canvas can be reused.

Please help and thanks.

Comment: 1. What do you get as value ('data') from subscription, is it of the right format/type ( MockDataModel[ ] )?

2. Are you sure you are using the this.data as intended? It seems that it should be of MockDataModel type, but at the end of the loop you push a Chart to each element of this.data while each element was already acquired from subscription? Are you really indending for this.data to be 2d array?

Comment: Also there where some errors that I made while copying the code, rectifying them. Sorry for that. It's not a push() performed in this.data but a simple assignment like this.data[i].chart = new Chart(ctx[i], {'data': chartData, 'type': 'doughnut' });

Comment: The value of ('data') received from subscription is like the following: [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "running": 5,
    "ordered": 3,
    "cancelled": 2,
    "request_sent": 4,
    "declined": 3
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "running": 2,
    "ordered": 3,
    "cancelled": 2,
    "request_sent": 4,
    "declined": 4
  }]

Comment: I was experimenting with chartJS actually, Hence the reason I had put "chart" property in MockDataModel to implement triggering events programmatically for specific graph later on.

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41280857/chart-js-failed-to-create-chart-cant-acquire-context-from-the-given-item it might prove useful