# My chart.js canvas disappears after hide() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js, toggle, hide

I'm trying to find out why the canvas in my code, in this case - a line chart, does not appear again after `toggle()`.
The `div` appears and disappears when clicking the "hide" button which causes the `toggle()`  function but the `div` is empty because the canvas does not appear. When I make the same chart outside of the ".library" div and don't use any `toggle()` or `hide()` functions it works.

(I'm using chart.js - yes, I have downloaded chart.js even though it is not in my code below)

```js
$(".library").hide();
$("#hide").on("click", () => {
  $(".library").toggle();
});


var lineData = {
  labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June"],
  datasets: [{
    fillColor: "rgba(172,194,132,0.4)",
    strokeColor: "#ACC26D",
    pointColor: "#fff",
    pointStrokeColor: "#9DB86D",
    data: [186, 156, 251, 144, 305, 236]
  }]
}
var line = document.getElementById('line').getContext('2d');
new Chart(line).Line(lineData);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.0.2/Chart.min.js'></script>

<button id="hide">hide</button>
<div class="library" id="chart">
    <canvas id="line" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello, if the below answer solved your issue, please consider accepting it by clicking the grey tick next to it :)

Answer (score 1):

The reason this is happening is that your canvas's parent, `.library` is hidden at the time of initialization, which sets the canvas height and width to 0. See this answer [Canvas height/width 0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32662713/7867822)

The solution is to first initialize the `canvas` and then hide the `.library` `div`. See code below:

```js
$(function() {
  
  $("#hide").on("click", () => {
    $(".library").toggle();
  });


  var lineData = {
    labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June"],
    datasets: [{
      fillColor: "rgba(172,194,132,0.4)",
      strokeColor: "#ACC26D",
      pointColor: "#fff",
      pointStrokeColor: "#9DB86D",
      data: [186, 156, 251, 144, 305, 236]
    }]
  }
  var line = document.getElementById('line').getContext('2d');
  new Chart(line).Line(lineData);
  
  $(".library").hide();

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.0.2/Chart.min.js'></script>


<button id="hide">hide</button>
<div class="library" id="chart">

  <canvas id="line" width="600" height="400"></canvas>

</div>
```